# Algorithm to find all convex quadrilaterals from the given list of 2d points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have to make a program to find all convex quadrilaterals from the given list of 2d points.
I have tried it with vector cross product but it doesn't seem to be a correct solution.

Maybe there is some effective algorithm to this problem but I can not find it.

This is an example case with inputs and outputs:

**Input**

```
Number of Points:
6
```

```
coordinates of points (x,y):
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
```

**Output**

```
Number of convex quadrilaterals:
9
```

Comment: Do you mean convex polygons?  I'm not clear why you are specifying a number of points if they're quadrilaterals (4 sided).

Comment: Oh, it's the number of points in the subsequent list, is that it?

Comment: At any rate, I think you can check if 4 points are the vertices of a convex quadrilateral by checking if the 4th point is outside the triangle defined by the first three points.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, it is Number of convex quadrilaterals. Thx for advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quadrilateral is convex if its diagonals intersect. Conversely, if two line segments intersect, then their four endpoints make a convex quadrilateral.

[image: convex quadrilateral on left, non-convex on right]

Every pair of points gives you a line segment, and every point of intersection between two line segments corresponds to a convex quadrilateral.

You can find the [points of intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/68063) using either the naïve algorithm that compares all pairs of segments, or the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). The former takes O(*n*<sup>4</sup>); and the latter O((*n*<sup>2</sup> + *q*) log *n*) (where *q* is the number of convex quadrilaterals). In the worst case *q* = Θ(*n*<sup>4</sup>) — consider *n* points on a circle — so Bentley–Ottmann is not always faster.

Here's the naïve version in Python:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

def intersection(s1, s2):
    """
    Return the intersection point of line segments `s1` and `s2`, or
    None if they do not intersect.
    """
    p, r = s1[0], s1[1] - s1[0]
    q, s = s2[0], s2[1] - s2[0]
    rxs = float(np.cross(r, s))
    if rxs == 0: return None
    t = np.cross(q - p, s) / rxs
    u = np.cross(q - p, r) / rxs
    if 0 < t < 1 and 0 < u < 1:
        return p + t * r
    return None

def convex_quadrilaterals(points):
    """
    Generate the convex quadrilaterals among `points`.
    """
    segments = combinations(points, 2)
    for s1, s2 in combinations(segments, 2):
        if intersection(s1, s2) != None:
            yield s1, s2
```

And an example run:

```py
>>> points = map(np.array, [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)])
>>> len(list(convex_quadrilaterals(points)))
9
```

Comment: With your example, I get : ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @LudoSchmidt: You're probably using a version of NumPy that is newer than I was using in December 2012